# Grid and limit issues with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I was trying to create a sinewave graph using Matplotlib for the parameters given as below.

> Create a figure of size 12 inches in width, and 3 inches in height.
> Name it as fig.
>
> Create an axis, associated with figure fig, using add_subplot. Name it
> as ax.
>
> Create a numpy array t with 200 values between 0.0 and 2.0. Use the
> 'linspace' method to generate 200 values.
>
> Create a numpy array v, such that v = np.sin(2.5*np.pi*t).
>
> Pass t and v as variables to plot function and draw a red line passing
> through the selected 200 points. Label the line as sin(t).
>
> Label X-Axis as Time (seconds).
>
> Label Y-Axis as Voltage (mV).
>
> Set Title as Sine Wave.
>
> Limit data on X-Axis from 0 to 2.
>
> Limit data on Y-Axis from -1 to 1.
>
> Mark major ticks on X-Axis at 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4,
> 1.6, 1.8, and 2.0.
>
> Mark major ticks on Y-Axis at -1, 0, and 1.
>
> Add a grid, whose linestyle is '--'.
>
> Add a legend.

Wrote the below and it almost came as required, but the expected graph is slightly different to what i write. I did gave the x and y limits but the graph seems to be taking further than that.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
t = np.linspace(0.0,2.0,200)
v = np.sin(2.5*np.pi*t)
ax.set(title='Sine Wave', xlabel='time (seconds)', ylabel='Voltage (mV)', xlim = (0,2), ylim=(-1,1))
xmajor = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0]
ymajor = [-1,0,1]
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(xmajor))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(ymajor))
plt.plot(t, v, label='sin(t)',color = 'red')
plt.legend()
plt.rc('grid', linestyle='--', color='black')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

My plot and expected:
[image: Attached my plot and expected]

couple of points here

1. The axis is not limiting to what i provided
2. the grid seems to be different.

Any ideas how to fix this please.

Updated Picture:
[image: Updated Picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with `ticker.FixedFormatter`. First, consider this solution:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
t = np.linspace(0.0,2.0,200)
v = np.sin(2.5*np.pi*t)
ax.set(title='Sine Wave', xlabel='time (seconds)', ylabel='Voltage (mV)', xlim = (0,2), ylim=(-1,1))
plt.xticks([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0])
plt.yticks([-1, 0, 1])
plt.plot(t, v, label='sin(t)',color = 'red')
plt.legend()
ax.grid(color='black', linestyle='--', dashes=[8, 6], alpha=0.5)
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

which results the following graph:

[image: results]

Notice I changed `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter` to `plt.xticks` which allows you directly to manipulate xticks.

You used `FixedFormatter`, which means the ticks location are fixed and you just name them - that's why the first 3 ticks on yaxis where -1, 0, 1 (your input), regardless of what their values was. Unless you have a good reason to use `matplotlib.ticker` (aka set locations of ticks or format them) I recommend to use simple `plt.xticks` to set the values of them.

Second change was to directly control the grid by using `ax.grid` instead of drawing a rectangle, which I believe is more correct. As you were pretty specific in your request on the dashed line (default "--" is different then what you ask for) I added `dashed=[float, float]` param. It allows you control the size of the dashes - you can maniputlate them as desired. The `alpha` param was added to give it more 'greyish' style but you can remove it

Comment: Ah got it. thanks for the explanation. but the expected grid seems to be different still (updated in the original post). I did change the line width, but still not getting this.

Comment: Edited my answer - I did a workaround for the grid you asked for